# Desperatly In need of all in one ajax function for jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
<input type="text" user" id="nick" />
<input type="text" user" id="message" />
<a href="#">Send</a>
```

Lets keep it simple. I have two input boxes and a send link. I want to send the nick and message to shoutbox.php, where i will insert these values in database and want to get all the results from the database and show it on the front end.

Now i have implemented the saving in database part but i cant get back the values from database to front end.

I am desperately in need of an jquery function in which i can just send the parameters and it will do all the job for me. I hope you guys might have such a function for yourselves.

Comment: You'll have to do an AJAX call.  You can use the [jQuery `.ajax()` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for that.  It allows you to return values in to a `success` callback.

Comment: Did you read the ajax documentation on the jQuery website?

Comment: What you are looking for is something like xajax for jquery. I have written my own xajaxish framework (that was 2009). Dont know, if there is an similar framework out there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the jQuery Ajax method to send data to the `shoutbox.php`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "shoutbox.php",
  data: { nick: "val_of_nick", msg: "val_of_msg" },
  success: function(data) {
    alert('Loaded: ' + data);
  }
});
```

Now in your `shoutbox.php`:

```
//read the sended data
$nickname = $_POST['nick'];
$msg = $_POST['msg'];

//to send data back, just use echo/print
echo 'You sended nickname: ' . $nickname . ' and msg: "' . $msg . '"';
```

If you run this code, then your js alert will show the `echo` line from `shoutbox.php`.

Hope this helps!

More info about jQuery ajax: [info](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: thankyou for your help. the code works fine now but there is a bit of confussion in this line { nick: "val_of_nick", msg: "val_of_msg" } i tried to replace it with $('#nick').val() but it doesnt work, what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as the answer :P If you use the following `data: { nick: $('#nick').val(), msg: $('#msg').val() }` then it should work. Otherwise check the data with an alert i.e.: `alert($('#msg').val());`.

Answer (score 0):

Just an example:

***HTML***

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" user" id="nick" name="nickname" /> <!-- use name ->
  <input type="text" user" id="message" name="message"/> <!-- use name -->
  <a href="#" id="send">Send</a>
</form>
```

***jQuery***

```
$('#send').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // prevent page reload on clicking of anchor tag
   $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'url_to_script',
     data: $('#myform').serialize(),
     dataType: 'json', // if you want to return JSON from php
     success: function(response) {
      // you can catch the data send from server within response
    }
   });
});
```

Now in your PHP side you can catch the send value via ajax like:

```
<?php
  ...
  $nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  ......
?>
```

---

Related refs:

- **[.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize)**
- **[.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/ajax)**